# custom annotations && aspects error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error Type referred to is not an annotation type

Tags: java, spring-boot, aop, java-annotations

I'm trying to make and aspect around a custom annotation.
I have this annotation:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public  @interface  BatchControlAnnotation{
    public Class<?> classType();
    public String batchName() default "none";
}
```

And I have this aspect pointcut:

```
    @Around("@annotation(BatchControlAnnotation)")
public Object  beforeBatch(ProceedingJoinPoint punto, BatchControlAnnotation batchControlAnnotation) throws Throwable {
    log.debug("HEMOS ENTRADO EN EL ASPECTO, HEMOS CONSEGUIDO LOS VALIRES DE LA ANOTACION CLASSTYPE : {} BATCHNAME {}", batchControlAnnotation.classType().getName(), batchControlAnnotation.batchName());
    log.debug("before");
    Object obj = null;
    try {
       obj = punto.proceed();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
       log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
       throw e;
    }
    log.debug("after");
    return obj;
}
```

But I'm getting this error and I can't understand why:

> org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration':
>   Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error Type referred to is not an
>   annotation type: *******
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:238)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:710)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:535)
>           at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
>           at com.karabati.ApibackApp.main(ApibackApp.java:61)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)

Does anyboy any idea about what's happening? Or how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I already saw where the problem is.

```
@Around("@annotation(BatchControlAnnotation)")
public Object  beforeBatch(ProceedingJoinPoint punto, BatchControlAnnotation batchControlAnnotation) throws Throwable
```

The problem is on this line:

```
@Around("@annotation(***BatchControlAnnotation***)")
```

The marked text has to refer to variable name on function `beforeBatch` definition, I was referring the type. So... changing `BatchControlAnnotation` to `batchControlAnnotation`, now it works fine.

It's funny to have to use the variable name instead the type, but is that way....